# Create a Merge request in GitLab and Auto Merge into master branch thru API call?

Tags: bash, github, jenkins, gitlab

So let's assume I want to update the master branch with some changes. This process it is done automatically by Jenkins agent but I want this process to be done in the following order:

1. Create a branch out of master. (I did, is done)
2. Thru API call I want to create a Merge Request and this merge request to be merged automatically into master. I created the API call MR request but I am struggling on how to Auto Merge into master????
3. Why I need this? (In case of failure of the new changes I want to have this option to revert manually back to the previous changes)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Accept MR](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr) endpoint with the `merge_when_pipeline_succeeds` parameter:

```
PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${ProjectId}/merge_requests/${MergeRequestIid}/merge?merge_when_pipeline_succeeds=true
```

Comment: merge_when_pipeline_succeeds ----> works only with GitLab CI/CD or with Jenkins CI/CD as well?